# pro*c dll fail when called from different clients

Tags: dll, oracle11g, crash, proc, mql4

I'm experiencing a weird behavior from a DLL function I have written to access an Oracle DB via Pro*C; specifically, it works fine when I call it from MQL4, and instead crashes at a specific line when called from a C client.

Crash reason says "Unhandled exception at 0x61428C74 (oranls11.dll) in GAClient.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00E368EC."

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8 64bit, though the development environment is set to build 32-bit DLL.
After several days debugging, I have reached the following conclusions:
- The crash occurs when EXEC SQL FETCH is called. Cursor opens fine.
- All parameters passed to the DLL function reach the crash point with exactly the same values, as I could gather from a series of fprintf() commands. This is also (and especially) true for the variable used to fetch into.
- Oracle Session Trace files are virtually identical, apparently showing Fetch, too, was successful
- Both clients (MT4.exe and GAClient.exe) are executed from command prompt, with the same set of environment variables (PATH, ORACLE_HOME, etc.)

I'm not even sure which code fragments would be useful to post at this stage; if someone has any idea where to start fixing this, I'd be more than happy to share.

Comment: Can you confirm all DLL-calls being made from MQL4/MT4.exe result in **`[pass]`**? Can you confirm each single DLL-call from Pro*C/GAClient.exe results in **`[fail]`**? Can you confirm to have MQL4/MT4.exe automated/scripted validation testing batteries or how have you done the regression testing for the **`DLL-under-test`** from MQL4?

Comment: I finally managed to solve this: The problem apparently lied in the C client-side declaration of the variable used to fetch the cursor into: changing that from char* to char[10] did the trick. (In MQL4 client it's declared as `uchar &pSymbol[]`). Thanks anyway for taking the time to look into this.

Comment: Great. MQL4 DLL wrappers are always a challenge. Definitely good to have a proper testing suite for both the single system-to-system "boundary" & the end-to-end integration testing. MQL4 wrappers often use re-defining calls to real DLL functions, due to the MQL4-side comfort of calling the DLL services, while having a need to match the DLL-expected passing byRef / byVal & NULL-terminated, byteLength pre-calculated string lenghts for operations on arrays and strings ( which are again arrays of bytes ), struct(s), plus counting .inc() / .dec() on referencing / de-referencing object instances...